# How to store a data continuously in a file?

Tags: android, file, io, android-service

I am implementing an app related to service, my service is running in background continuously and return a `String`.
I want to store the string in a file and retrieve when I want. The file contains first String info to last String (without overwriting).

If any one has solution,please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried something? have you googled something? have you got some working or broken code?

Comment: Please try something to find out solution for your question and if your are getting some problems in that then you can post question with your error,it will make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
FileOutputStream fos = null;
String FILENAME = "Your File Name";

fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

// write your bytes using fos

fos.write(Bytes to be saved);

fos.close();


// to read a file

FileInputStream fis = null;
fis = youractivity.openFileInput(FILENAME);
StringBuilder builer = new StringBuilder("");

                                        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(fis);
String line = null;
                                        while((line=dis.readLine()) != null)
{
   builer.append(line);
}

dis.close();
fis.close();
```